# Change the background to another color

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to change the backgroundColor  to a different color but it doesn't work, here's the command:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

I do it at `main.ts`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this , in the `index.html` put the main.ts in the `<body></body>`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's work thank you , why you need to put the main.js in the body tags ?